# Embedded PDF always appearing over Absolutely positioned elements

Tags: html, css, pdf, jquery-ui

We have a page where a PDF is embedded, and are trying to pop drop-down menus, jQuery UI dialogs, etc. over the PDF document which is currently displayed.

The problem is that the PDF is ALWAYS taking the 'front' position, so any elements dynamically created appear behind it. This was a common problem with Flash back in the days of DHTML, and here we are again.

Is this the kind of behavior to expect from PDF, or is there a way to override it? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What tag are you using to embed the PDF? What browser does this happen in?

Comment: It's an embed tag. This happens in all browsers; it's worst in IE obviously. Strangely, changing the 'overflow' values of the elements I'm trying to position on top has some influence, but nothing provides a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try "shimming" an iframe under the elements.

Comment: Any examples on how we do this?