# Embedded pdf displays in front / on top of absolutely positioned html elements

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

PDF embedded with embed as well as iframe, gives same results

[I have found this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911329/embedded-pdf-always-appearing-over-absolutely-positioned-elements) but I need a detailed description of how this answer solved the OP's problem, sice theres not much to go on in the answer there.

My embedded pdf displays on top of all absolutely positioned elements on my page in Internet Explorer 6 through 8. I attempted the iframe shimming technique using jQuery.bgiframe, modified to trigger in all IE browsers, without results

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible.

Keep in mind, that plugins are separate programs from the browser that communicate with the browser over a very simple API. For the browser to be able to draw over the plugins canvas, they would need to communicate much more closely than the plugin API allows, so that the plugin doesn't redraw over anything the the browser draw on the plugins canvas.